# Exchange Web Services (EWS) API "To" header for alias

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have an inbox set up in exchange, **`hello@mycompany.com`**

Additionally, there is an alias for this, **`news@mycompany.com`**, so all emails to the **`news`** address end up in the **`hello`** inbox.

Ideally, I want to be able to tell which alias an email has been sent to, using EWS.

When I send an email to **`news@mycompany.com`**, and examine the Internet headers of the message using Microsoft Outlook, the **`To:`** header reads **`To: Hello <news@mycompany.com>`** which is exactly what I want to see.

However, using EWS, when I look at the [ToRecipients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.torecipients%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property of the message, the reported email address is always that of the primary SMTP address. Also the [InternetMessageHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemschema.internetmessageheaders%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property of the Webservices.Data.Item does not contain the **`To:`** property. I also can't seem to see the correct address using [EWSEditor](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewseditor) to examine all the properties of the message.

The answer to [this forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/56fffc5f-4ba2-4613-af53-ec17c61d7f46) seems to suggest that,

> ...The Information about the actual email address a message is sent to is stored in the recipients collection which you can't access (outside of exportmessage) in EWS...

How would I go about doing this programatically so I can find the correct **`To:`** address?

Comment: I've ran into the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @HeavenCore , unfortunately not, we ended up adding a hashtag into the email subject line to tell our app how to process the email. e.g. a subject of "blah blah #news" would be processed as a news item.

Comment: Dang, thanks anyway, if i find anything i'll let you know.

Comment: Do you have any news on this ? Same problem here...

Comment: @BoasEnkler unfortunately not, the project is sitting unused, so I've yet to have a chance to try anything else. Frank's solution looks to be worth trying though! Let us know if you find it works :)

Comment: Using a hastag in the subject is prone to user error. This is very annoying as I need to know who the intended address was for, whilst having all of the emails arrive in one mailbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    private static string GetToAddress()
    {
        ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService();
        exService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        exService.Url = new Uri("https://youraddress/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x007D,MapiPropertyType.String);
        PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
                                    {PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS, ItemSchema.MimeContent};

        FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = exService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));
        foreach (Item itItem in fiResults.Items)
        {
            itItem.Load(psPropSet);
            Object valHeaders;
            if (itItem.TryGetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS, out valHeaders))
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"To:.*<(.+)>");
                Match match = regex.Match(valHeaders.ToString());
                if (match.Groups.Count == 2)
                    return match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
            return ToAddress;
        }
        return "Cannot find ToAddress";
    }
```

The code is from:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-au/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/1e5bbde0-218e-466e-afcc-cb60bc2ba692

Comment: Worked for me. I needed to add a bit more logic for parsing out the 'To:' header for multiple recipients and over multiple lines.

Comment: Any experiences with this solution?

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the answer. Worked exactly how I needed it to.

Comment: ToAddress is not defined anywhere?

Comment: This looks great, but I have a case where the alias address is not enclosed in angle brackets. Any idea how to account for both scenarios? That is, the To: email could look like this, 'To: User Name <username@contoso.com>', or like this, 'To: username@contoso.com'