# Can you get PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 0x007D from the .Net Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We are using alias email addresses to match incoming emails with a client.  All the alias addresses are delivered into one Primary emailbox.

The alias address is not listed in the ToRecipients.  If I open the email in OWA and look at the message details, I can see the alias in the To: property of the message header.

I tried using the graph.microsoft.com/beta endpoint to get the internetMessageHeader.  It worked great(I was surprised.)  Unfortunately, the To: property is missing from the response. (The From: property is missing too.)

The problem is the same as this question about using EWS.  [Exchange Web Services (EWS) API "To" header for alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213571/exchange-web-services-ews-api-to-header-for-alias)

Is there an equivalent way to get the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 0x007D property using the Microsoft-Graph API .Net?

I tried:

```
var myvar = await graphClient.Users[inbox].Messages[message.Id].Request().Select("transportMessageHeaders").GetAsync();
```

But I got this error: Message: Could not find a property named 'transportMessageHeaders' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can access MAPI properties as [extended properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get) in the Microsoft Graph API.

The URL construct you'd want would look something like:

```
GET /me/messages/{message-id}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties(
    $filter=id eq 'String 0x007D')
```

Since you're using the .NET Graph library, you would modify your code above like so:

```
var myvar = await graphClient.Users["user"]
    .Messages[message.Id]
    .Request().Select("singleValueExtendedProperties")
    .Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x007D')").GetAsync();

string transportHeaders = myVar.SingleValueExtendedProperties.First().Value;
```